# Woocommerce purchase event

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce store and I have integration with manufacturer based on JSON, where I'm parsing his JSON and adding his product quantities to woocommerce warehouse.

But additionally I have my own stock of this same products, that's why I need 2 ecommerce warehouses - for manufacturer stock and for my own stock.

I've build those 2 warehouses, where my stock is on separate mysql table than woocommerce, but now I need to add event, that if someone purchase product, the quantity of product will be decreased from my warehouse (external from woocommerce).

How to find woocommerce purchase event, to which I could add function which will decrease my stock product quantity in not woocommerce table?

Comment: Having two warehouses seems counterproductive. Does your manufacturer not provide product id or sku or any other unique product code, that can be used to distinguish between your and their products? You could also add a custom field or post meta on products added from the manufacturer

Answer (score 2):

You could use the woocommerce's 'woocommerce_after_pay_action' hook.

Reference: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Add this code in a must-use plugin or in functions.php

```
function after_purchase_action($order) {
    // do something
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_pay_action', 'after_purchase_action', 10, 1 );
```